# resource collection and meta laravel collection custome request

Tags: laravel, http, collections, resources, httpclient

my controller:

```
  $data = json_decode(collect($data['d']));
     $meta = json_decode(collect($data['d']));
     $reps = new ResourceCollection($data . $meta);
```

resouce collection

```
 'data' => $this->collection,
        'meta' => $this->collection,
```

I have 2 data that I store in the variable $data to store and data and $meta to store the meta I want to display the data and meta from the request sata to my collection, I have tried several ways but it doesn't work